# Auto-populate field based on other field when selected

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, field-calculator

I’m dealing with thousands of points in my project and requires me to select points base on distance from other line features (i.e roads). Since the possibility for some points to overlap are high, I design my work so that the selected points will turn red whilst non-selected points remains black. I don't want the points to be selected twice and belongs to two roads.

For this to work, I added another 2 text field i.e “Road” and “Marked”. After selecting the points base on location from the road, l then select all the points and fill the “Road” field with new road name, and on “Marked” field as X to change its color and differ it from non-selected points. By this, I can later remove the selected points using ‘base on attribute’ option.

There will be hundreds of road to deal with and be given new name but no matter what its name, the “Marked” field will be an X and the points that corresponding to it will change color. I can manually fill the the “Marked” field using the field calculator but am looking for the “Marked” field to be filled automatically every time the “Road” field is not empty, or else it will remain blank.

I'm using ArcMap 10.6.

Comment: Please add witch software you use and what are your data format as potential solutions may differ depending on these information

Comment: Opps....Sorry. I'm using ArcMap 10.6.

Comment: "Automatic" means different things to different folks. It's not possible to make database changes spontaneously occur, so you need to clarify what process you want to occur, under what conditions, describe your effort to make this happen, and provide details on what happened instead.